# jquery datepicker shows automatically in modal dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datepicker

Just got the datepicker working in my modal dialog, the first time i open it it doesn't open automatically (which is expected). If i close the dialog then open it the next time it comes up automatically (which I definitely do not want).

```
$(function () {

$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});

$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
    }
});
$("#opener").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

});

Here is the [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/abidmix/dBLn5/1/)

All efforts so far have not worked, what I have tried so far includes:

- In the .open event setting focus to something else
- adding autofocus attribute to other controls in the modal
- setting a default value to the datepicker (hardcoded)

Any tips or help would be great? Is it even possible can't seem to find anything on jquery docs.

Comment: I'll continue to update the efforts list with new things.

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/dBLn5/157/

Comment: That still only works on the first try. Once I close and reopen it then pops up automatically. Doesn't appear to be a browsing issue either as it works on IE and chrome (haven't got FF installed to test).

Comment: Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/dBLn5/158/

Comment: Worked in fiddle, in my project might need to do a bit of "fiddling" my open event loads a partial view and that partial view contains the datepicker(s) in question i'll post back and confirm when I get it working. Thanks though definitely on track now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to note about my experience each datepicker (I have multiple on the form) must have a different class-attribute name.

Inside the partialview that contains the datepickers I hate the following javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $(".meetingDate1").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
    $(".meetingDate2").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
});
```

Then in the main page that opens the modal and returns the partial view I have the following:

```
 $(".booking").click(function () {
    $(".meetingDate1").datepicker("disable");
    $(".meetingDate2").datepicker("disable");
    $("#bookingForm").dialog({
        position: { my: "center", at: "top", of: window },
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Modal Title Here',
        modal: true,
        width: 990,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            // load the partial view containing form controls
            $(this).load('@Url.Action("Create", "Booking")');
            $(".meetingDate1").datepicker("enable");
            $(".meetingDate2").datepicker("enable");
        },
        buttons: {
            "Book Meeting": function () {
                 // call controller method with bookedmeeting storedproc
             },
             Cancel: function () {
                 $(this).dialog("close");
             }
         }
    });
});
```

So to reemphasize I disable the datepicker on the 'click' event and then enable it in the 'open' event. Thanks to [hackerman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713277/jquery-datepicker-shows-automatically-in-modal-dialog?noredirect=1#comment51364594_31713277) for the assistance.